# search for tag(s) in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm saving markup this way:

```
var nav_large = nav_container.html();
```

The saved markup looks like this:

```
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Toolbox</a></li>
    <li><a href="/starten">Starten</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="/basis">Basis</a>
      <div class="main-navigation-cart">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="">KOMPONENTEN</a></li>
          <li><a href="">JAVASCRIPT</a></li>
          <li><a href="">ICONS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/komponenten">Komponenten</a></li>
    <li><a href="/sso">Single Sign-On</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Now I need to be able to search after `ul` for example. The markup from the `nav_container` has been removed at this stage of the script.

Hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: Convert `nav_large` to a jQuery object and traverse it as usual. Alternatively, detach the `nav_container` from the DOM and save it in a variable.

Comment: `$(nav_large).find('ul')`?

Comment: @Johan This ends up in the following error: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Toolbox</a></li>
    <li><a href="/starten">Starten</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="/basis">Basis</a>
      <div class="main-navigation-cart">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="">KOMPONENTEN</a></li>
          <li><a href="">JAVASCRIPT</a></li>
          <li><a href="">ICONS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/komponenten">Komponenten</a></li>
    <li><a href="/sso">Single Sign-On</a></li>
  </ul>`

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof nav_large)` return?

Comment: @Johan It does return `String`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7v3SQ/

Comment: @Johan Thanks, man. But since I got two `ul`, shouln't find `$(html).find('ul')` those 2 `ul`?

Comment: @Johan stupid question. I think I got a working solution now. I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: It's not stupid. This will probably make you understand it better: http://jsfiddle.net/7v3SQ/1/ find() will only look for descending ul's

Comment: Stupid was related to that descending ul stuff. Thank you very much for your help!